# How to make color bright with SGR function according to ISO/IEC 6429:1992?

Tags: terminal, escape-characters

On [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#3-bit_and_4-bit) I found the following code for bright colors for SGR (select graphic rendition) function

```
FG   BG
90  100     Bright Black
91  101     Bright Red
92  102     Bright Green
93  103     Bright Yellow
94  104     Bright Blue
95  105     Bright Magenta
96  106     Bright Cyan
97  107     Bright White
```

On wiki it is said "Later terminals added the ability to directly specify the "bright" colors with 90–97 and 100–107." However, I can't find these codes in ECMA-48/5th. There are only parameter values from 0 to 65. Could anyone explain these codes on wiki and how to make color bright according to ISO/IEC 6429:1992?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECMA-48 doesn't define "bright colors".   That came about due to PC-displays.  It's an [FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#bold_vs_16colors).

ECMA-48 defines colors with codes 0-7, both foreground and background.  Text (ECMA-48) can be displayed with bold. PC-displays would not show ***bold*** text (equating bold to ***bright*** is reversing cause/effect), but used brightness for that feature.  Since the normal (non-bold) yellow came out as *brown*, etc., in xterm and other terminals (such as Linux console), colors 8-15 were a desirable feature (in xterm, [**boldColors**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#bold_vs_16colors) resource).

```
   boldColors (class ColorMode)
           Specifies whether to combine bold attribute with colors like
           the IBM PC, i.e., map colors 0 through 7 to colors 8 through
           15.  These normally are the brighter versions of the first 8
           colors, hence bold.  The default is "true"
```

Some *applications* referred to that as *bright colors* (which is unnecessarily restrictive).  You'd have to go back a [while](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_52) to see which term came first.  In xterm, it was initially referred to just as ["16-colors"](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_39).  In the [aixterm](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=aixterm-command) manpage, neither bold or bright is used:

```
30..37 foreground colors—Xh, H
40..47 background colors—Xh, H
90..97 foreground colors—Xh, H
100..107 background colors—Xh, H
```

(the Xh and H refer to types of terminals).

Linux console, by the way, has ["recently"](https://web.archive.org/web/20120315035130/https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) (in the past 2-3 years) added the aixterm codes 90-107 for "bright" colors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I understand correctly - the codes I posted are taken from xterm specs?

Comment: See updates.  What you posted is based on second-hand comments based on some unidentified application, probably several years later, not any documentation written for xterm.